# How to print RTP and RTCP packet messages using JsSIP?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtp, rtcp, jssip

I am using JsSIP to make SIP calls. I am able to see Signalling messages like From, To, Via in the console.

[image]

In the same way, can we see RTP and RTCP packet transmission messages?

Answer (score 0):

No.
You can see the signalling part (SIP or JSEP), but not the media part in the console. RTP/RTCP are the media protocols.

Answer (score 0):

You can diagnose RTP headers and RTCP packets by using chrome's webrtc-internals dump files.

https://tokbox.com/blog/how-to-get-a-webrtc-diagnostic-recording-from-chrome-49/

https://github.com/fippo/dump-webrtc-event-log